# When do we need path-like structure named-route (for example, '/a/b/c') in flutter?

Tags: flutter, path-finding, navigator

At first , I think when pushing  '/a/b/c' it will do 3 pushes , and the stack will have 3 pages(widgets) :

1. first push the page for a
2. then push the page for b
3. push the page for c at last

But after a test , the pushing  '/a/b/c' will only push one page(c). It's the same as define a route like '/c'.

So, When do we need this kind of multiple component path-like structure named-routers '/a/b/c'? Because I think the one-component '/c' is enough for us .

Comment: Are u asking  purpose regarding named routes or the 'a/b/c' , if it's the named routes i think controlling navigation with named routes makes it abit easier. i save a static string in Every class that's a screen and return those rather than the class constructors. Not sure why you are trying to push 3 screens at a time, could u give me some insight for future reference?

Comment: I don't wanna push 3 screens at a time , The thing I'm confused is that when do we need to define a 'a/b/c' route?  Because I think  the 'c' route is enough

Comment: If you want to push three pages at once, you need to call three different push operations. Now back to your question: imagine that you have a huge list of routes. /a/b/c just helps organize them. just like on SO: it has different urls for questions, tags, users... . It just helps keep everything organized

Comment: @TheAnonymousKoder Thanks , Can u give a more specific example of organization? Because I think 'c' is more clearly than '/a/b/c' for the meaning of push one page

Comment: /stackoverflow.com(/a)/questions(/b)/questionid(/c)

Comment: What about https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking?